# How to integrate SSO and Formio forms to Laravel website using Mysql?

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on, offline-mode, formio

I am looking for an approach to integrate SSO and Formio forms to my Laravel website.

- Can use SQL connector of formio with Laravel?
- How to integrate SSO with Laravel?
- If it can't use SQL connector with Laravel, can't use Mysql in Laravel for using Formio?
- I can't find examples to implement offline forms in a php project.

Comment: This question is way to broad for stack overflow. Please come back after you've tried to solve your problem and you have a specific issue.